# Cisco VPN Client Neither Installed Nor Uninstalled

Tags: vpn, uninstall, cisco-vpn-client

I'm trying to install the Cisco VPN client on a Windows 7 x64 machine. The last time, the installer froze, and I had to kill the process.

Now when I run the installer, it tells me to uninstall through Add/Remove Programs. But I don't have an entry for Cisco VPN there, since it never completed installing.

How can I purge the remnants of this software from my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the Cisco Systems folder in your program files. That's the best you can do.