# Can't Install Cisco VPN on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, cisco-vpn-client

I've tried various methods to install Cisco VPN on a Windows 7 64-bit machine. I keep getting the same error:

> Error 27850. Unable to manage networking component.
>
> Operating system corruption may be preventing installation.

Awesomely evil. What bothers me is that one of my co-workers, who has an image of my machine, who also saw this problem, ran a particular installer and it worked for him. But it didn't work for me.

I have tried the following Cisco VPN client installers (based on the EXE file names):

- x64 client
- x64 5.0.07.0240 - k9 - BETA client
- Windows 7 client (wasn't compatible with x64)

They all give me the same error (minus the latter, which wouldn't run). I'm also suspecting this may be from a [partial uninstall](https://superuser.com/questions/255296/cisco-VPN-client-neither-installed-nor-uninstalled) which may not have been properly purged (and lead to [restore point corruption](https://superuser.com/questions/257582/chicken-and-egg-cant-restore-system-point-and-cant-run-scan-disk)). Both of those issues were resolved, but maybe there are some dregs left in my system.

Comment: Any particular reason why you are using an outdated client?

Comment: @BroScience that's what the company wants me to use. I'm no longer at said company, thankfully.

Comment: For what it's worth  0290 is much more stable than 0240. i would try that after cleanly removing 0240

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into a similar problem on a Windows 10 machine where the VPN installation was failing with the Unable to manage networking component error. I tried all of the fixes, including the registry fix above, and nothing worked. It turned out that the machine had Kaspersky Internet Security installed, and its self-defense function was blocking changes to the networking that were required during install. I had disabled Kaspersky earlier when I was trying to figure out the problem, but it had no effect. There were also no notifications that it was stopping the installer. When I manually disabled self-defense, the installer worked perfectly. I'm sure other security programs can similarly interfere.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution at https://chapter10.wordpress.com/2012/11/19/error-27850/

You need to change the value of the the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\MaxNumFilters
```

Default is **8**, maximum is **14**.

I got this to work with x64 5.0.07.0440-k9 client.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me. That is a good solution though.

Answer (score 1):

Step by Step with screenshots to fix this Cisco VPN error.

http://www.itsystemadmin.com/error-27850-unable-to-manage-networking-component/

Comment: explain the info here and avoid using a link

Comment: It doesn't work.